# Only buttons on first page of table are clickable when using pagination - List.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I recently asked a question about the inability to click a table row and popup an alert when on any page but the first using List.js pagination.

This was solved by adjusting my click event to:

```
$('#test-list').on('click', 'tr', function() {
alert("These work, but the rest don't :(")
})
```

Now I seem to be having the same trouble with buttons, but am not sure how to fix the click event.

This is the click event as it sits:

```
$(".test-button").on("click", function () 
{ alert("These work, but the rest don't :("); 
});
```

Here's a codepen so you can check out the issue:

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/gpdgvj

It's probably also a simple fix, but I cannot come up with the solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the buttons use a static reference to bind the event and then pass the button class like this:

```
$("#test-list tbody").on("click", ".test-button",function () {
     alert("These work, but the rest don't :( ..... but now seems working :) "); 
});
```

working pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbPpPK